# Export/import Joomla plugin settings

Tags: php, joomla3.0

I have been googling for a while trying to find some tips how to add export/import to a Joomla 3.x plugin settings but no luck. 
I want to add to a system plugin the possibility of export/import its settings.
Can someone give me some guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Ask the owner of the plugin.
2. Post a topic on the plugin support forum.
3. Post a topic on the official Joomla forums.

Comment: Thanks for your tips, but maybe I wasn't being clear enough. The plugin is mine and I am trying to add that possibility but don't know how. Could you please give me some tips how to achieve it?

Comment: Oh right, well then you'd need to write some PHP code to obtain all of the variables and values, and dump them to a txt file. You could Google and probably find what you're after. Then you'd need to create a frontend for it.